# How do I manually Initiate outbound communications in c# like skype and torrent?

Tags: c#, wcf, network-protocols

I wants to make chat and file transfer application without any central server. for this, I wants to initiate outbound communication in c#.

it would be great and many thankful, If somebody knows about this as I am stuck here from last one month.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a api available for this but if there isn't or you don.'t want to use an api then sockets are the only way.
If your initiating outbound communication then TCPClient is the class you will need or you can use the Socket class itself. Something has to be listening for incoming connection though, TcpListener is another class which makes this easier but again i 'm fairly sure you can just use the socket class again.

All depends on the protocols you are using...

Comment: I have used socket and TCPClient but its not working over internet, its working over LAN only.

For this I downloaded lot of socket and TCPClient Chat applications and try to connect over internet but not get any success.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having issues with NAT (network address translation) - this is basically why having a centralised server is a good idea in the first place..

You'll need to configure your router to allow external connections to a particular port, and forward them to your listening socket - either by a static mapping or you might be able to use upnp to automatically request a port forwarding from your client app.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13285/Using-UPnP-for-Programmatic-Port-Forwardings-and-N I was trying port forword by software then I've got an error as https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpea60jcdjlqzhu/PortForwordSoftwareError.JPG I've tried as: 1. disabled/off the firewall 2. I'm using windows 8 o/s 3. I also have upnp enabled router image url: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbtqpkof7m3v4lp/IMG_20032014_161911.png

Comment: How do I automatically map port without using NAT-PMP and/or UPnP?

Comment: You can't automatically really.. You could add a static mapping though on your firewall, which would at least be good enough to check your code works, then you could progress to getting the upnp bit working

Comment: I have done with upnp but if someone deactivated upnp on router then how it can be possible port forwarding?

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head there.. This is why having a central server is a good idea. It turns out that often it's only required during session initialisation (lookup STUN for more details)

Comment: You could also have a sort of connection broker service running behind your firewall with a static nat mapping to it, which would allow multiplexing client communication through that one NATted port, but that's probably asking too much of a user for something that's intended to be simplr

Comment: Yep that's what the bittorrent tracker is for - your bittorrent client initiates outbound connection to the tracker, it's a centralised server that assists in setting up the peer to peer connection